# Use another MapStruct mapper only inside an expression clause

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

I have a mapper that, for a particular attribute of the target class, needs to choose one from a list of objects inside the source object, and map it using a differente mapper class.

Simplifying it a lot, the `Game` class contains a list of `Transaction` objects, and my `GameMapper` class looks like this:

```
@Component
@Mapper(injectionStrategy = InjectionStrategy.CONSTRUCTOR, uses = {TransactionMapper.class, EventMapper.class})
public interface GameMapper {

@Mapping(target = "transaction", 
    expression = "java(transactionMapper.transactionToDto(findTransactionForPlayer(game, idPlayer)))")
GameResultDto gameToGameResultDto(Game game, Long idPlayer);

// Some more methods

}
```

The thing is, `EventMapper` gets generated as a `private final EventMapper eventMapper;` attribute inside `GameMapperImpl`, but `TransactionMapper` is not, so the build fails because MapStruct cannot find `transactionMapper`.

My best guess is that this is due to no other methods in `GameMapper` using `TransactionMapper` explicitly, so Mapstruct decides that it's not needed and doesn't inject it in the implementation.

So... is there any way to force MapStruct to include the mappers in the `uses` clause, even it if looks like they are not being used, or any other way to work around this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> My best guess is that this is due to no other methods in `GameMapper` using `TransactionMapper` explicitly, so Mapstruct decides that it's not needed and doesn't inject it in the implementation.

That is correct. MapStruct will not inject mappers from `Mapper#uses` if they are not used by MapStruct.

What you could do is to use an abstract class.

e.g.

```
@Mapper(injectionStrategy = InjectionStrategy.CONSTRUCTOR, componentModel = "spring", uses = {TransactionMapper.class, EventMapper.class})
public abstract class GameMapper {

    @Autowired
    protected TransactionMapper transactionMapper;

    @Mapping(target = "transaction", 
        expression = "java(transactionMapper.transactionToDto(findTransactionForPlayer(game, idPlayer)))")
    public abstract GameResultDto gameToGameResultDto(Game game, Long idPlayer);

    // Some more methods

}
```

Comment: has this changed since the answer? I came up with this solution on my end as well, but it'd be a lot cleaner to keep using an interface, and have MapStruct create a constructor that includes my dependency (that is managed by Spring). for now if I only use an expression, such as here, my dependency is not getting added as a constructor parameter.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your question @agiro. If you MapStruct to automatically detect mappings and not to use expression then you can use `Mapper#uses`. However, if you do not want to add your class to `Mapper#uses` then you'll have to do it like in this answer

Comment: I tried `uses` but it only works if I map with `source - target`in the `@Mapping`. I need to use an expression and with that the generator doesn't include my custom class in the generated code.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a hacky solution. By adding a `List<TransactionDto> dummy(List<Transaction> transaction);` method to `GameMapper`, I have tricked MapStruct into thinking I'm really using `TransactionMapper` for something and it has successfully added it to `GameMapperImpl`.

I'm still open to non-hacky solutions, though :)